# How to change the UINavigationbar dynamically in iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, dynamic, uinavigationcontroller

Like the iPhone browser, when you tap the URL text field, all navigation bar expand and "Cancel" button show up. Hit the "Cancel" button and the bar change back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `titleView` in the navigation bar, which you can switch or animate between two display states, depending on what the user is doing or tapping.

Read the "Configuring the Navigation Item Object" section of Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1) documentation for more information on how to customize the navigation bar.